# No 100 rep received at 200 rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Listen guys, you know that 100 points you receive when you reach 200 reputation, I am now on 300 and I still didn't get, it's quite weird.I am not sure why, help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only get the 100 rep association bonus when you join a stackexchange site while having another SE site that has 200+ rep. [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work). You only have (one) account.

Comment: So for instance if I go to stackoverflow will I get 100 rep on stackexchange?

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov Yep, on that site.